# making a button invisible on a form when the timer session is up

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to make a button invisible when the timer on my page is up. The timer on my page is set to be up in 1 minute. Once the timer is up, I want to set the button visible=false, but the button does not become invisible.

Below is the code for the timer:

```cs
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" runat="server" Interval="1000" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>

        <div class="sticky">
            <span style="border: 2px; color: red; font-size: 25px;">Time Remaining: &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"></asp:Label></span>
            <br />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

below is the button on the page:

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" Text="Test" OnClick="test_click" />
```

My aspx.cs code is like so:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace SendBulkEmail
{
    public partial class WebForm4 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                if (Session["CountdownTimer"] == null)
                {
                    Session["CountdownTimer"] = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
                }
                TimeSpan current = (TimeSpan)Session["CountdownTimer"];
                Label1.Text = current.ToString("%m") + " minutes and " + current.ToString("%s") + " seconds";
            }
        }

        protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TimeSpan ts2sec = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2); // 2 seconds

            TimeSpan ts = (TimeSpan)Session["CountdownTimer"]; // current remaining time from Session
            TimeSpan current = ts - ts2sec; // Subtract 5 seconds
            Label1.Text = current.ToString("%m") + " minutes and " + current.ToString("%s") + " seconds";
            Session["CountdownTimer"] = current;  // put new remaining time in Session 

            if (current.Seconds == 0 && current.Minutes == 0)
            {
                Session["CountdownTimer"] = "";
                Timer1.Enabled = false;

                Label1.Text = "Your Session is timed out. ";

                btnTest.Visible = false;
            }

        }

        protected void test_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string a = "This is Test";
        }
    }
}
```

I am setting the `btnTest.Visible = false;` in my `Timer_tick` event when the time is up, but the `btnTest` does not become invisible. Below is the entire code for .cs *code-behind* page:

```cs
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm4.aspx.cs" Inherits="SendBulkEmail.WebForm4" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="src1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <div>
            <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" runat="server" Interval="1000" />

            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="StockPricePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" />
                </Triggers>
                <ContentTemplate>

                    <div class="sticky">
                        <span style="border: 2px; color: red; font-size: 25px;">Time Remaining: &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label></span>
                        <br />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>

        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" Text="Test" OnClick="test_click" />

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button is not in the `UpdatePanel` - your code is setting `btnTest.Visible = false`, but is not updating the page. The current page state becomes invalid (clicking the button will fail), but no visible update happens. **Move your button code into the `UpdatePanel`, as follows:**

```cs
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="StockPricePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="sticky">
            <span style="border: 2px; color: red; font-size: 25px;">Time Remaining: &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label></span>
            <br />
            <div>
                <asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" Text="Test" OnClick="test_click" />
            </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Additionally, as `TimeSpan` can go negative, I recommend updating your check in  `Timer1_Tick` event handler, as follows:

```cs
if (current.TotalMilliseconds <= 0)
{
    Session["CountdownTimer"] = "";
    Timer1.Enabled = false;

    Label1.Text = "Your Session is timed out. ";

    btnTest.Visible = false;
}
```

This will prevent any issues with *not perfectly divisible values* such as decrement of 7 seconds at a time instead of 2.

Comment: The above code works. Is it possible to just grey out the background where the btnTest exists. My page has lot of radiobutton list and other elements. I am displaying the time out timer at the top and the btnTest is at the bottom of the screen. I just want to grey out the entire screen and put a redirect button so that user can click it and redirected to first page.

Comment: @Anjali I'd use an `asp:Panel` tag in the same `UpdatePanel` - you'd have to figure out the CSS, it's effectively a server-side rendered `div` element - so you can define a CSS class and assign it to that panel with a `CssClass` attribute; then you can toggle it visible at the same time (or instead of) as hiding the button. The important aspect with WebForms is keeping dynamically updated elements that you don't want to "round-trip" to take effect inside your `UpdatePanel`.